# Check if user Likes Page with JS API?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbjs

I know this has been asked a bunch of times, but I have only seen serverside solutions.

I'm running an iframe app that is embedded into a page as a tab. I want be test to see if the page is liked or not without prompting the user for anything.

Is there a way to do this with just JavaScript? The platoform we are building on is ASPX and I dont really have the option of going serverside.

Comment: you can find the complete answer here [Facebook how to check if user has liked page and show content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246449/facebook-how-to-check-if-user-has-liked-page-and-show-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not available because you need to inspect the http post parameter called signed_request and this isn't available on the client side.  If the user has authenticated with your app and given you permissions to read their likes/interests, then you could then check with javascript api but I'm guessing you wouldn't want to make them approve your app just for this.

Comment: Thats what I was fearing! Thanks anyways