# facebook like button - do you know if web user likes your page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

im bulding web app (sweepstakes), where user has to insert his data AND like one or maybe more facebook pages. Then he can continue and participate in sweepstakes. he cannot participate if he doesnt click on like button. So i have to know that user has clicked on the like button. How do i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer similar post may be can help you out.

[Facebook how to check if user has liked page and show content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246449/facebook-how-to-check-if-user-has-liked-page-and-show-content)

thanks.

Comment: thank you. But is possible to do it without using facebook application. So the user doesnt have to give permissions etc?

Comment: I don't think so as you want specific functionality. Application is needed when you want to operate / check some functionality related to facebook over to your page.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that aside from the technical capability, this is actually against Facebook's regulations so this question is actually moot.