# Remeber if user clicked on sharebutton for facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I've searched the web for this, but I only could find stuff about the like button.

The question is simple:
Is it possible to check if a facebookuser has clicked on my sharelink (http://www.facebook.be/sharer.php?...)?

It's a short question, so I hope fast response!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tracking link which redirects to the facebook page and allows you to know if the user clicked on the button. For instance : `domain.tld/redirect.php?url=http://facebook.be...`

If users are visitors, you can simply set a cookie and verify when you display the link if the cookie exists or not. But they can delete the cookie, so give us more details if security is important.

If users are logged, you can update a SQL row or something similar.

Another solution: set a cookie with javascript when the user clicks on the link, it's doesn't require to modify the link, just add an event

Comment: I've just realized that it was perhaps not your question, sorry in this case.

Comment: If it'S not an answer to his question, delete it

Comment: i don't know, we have to wait for the OP'answer

Comment: These are indeed some solutions but I was wondering if you could check this with some facebook api. Unfortunately I'm starting to think it's impossible, so this answer may help some other people if they are searching for the same problem.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. Maybe you can read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246449/facebook-how-to-check-if-user-has-liked-page-and-show-content), i don't know how Facebook api works, so i can't help you. Good luck!

Comment: The problem with these work arounds is the fact that you don't now for certain that they've shared the link. They may have clicked on the first share button, but afterwards they need to confirm the share. So if they cancel, the work around still tels me the user has shared the link ...