# How to create a facebook page to promote a deal

Tags: facebook

As my fan page has been moved to timeline  and I had to move to a facebook app to add a welcome tab on my page which links to a image to do "Like Gatting" (http://www.facebook.com/LuviaDotCom/app_190322544333196). It takes some time to load the image. I am working on it.

My question is if I want to create a page to do the following.

- I send a link to user.
- The user goes to the url and a FB page loads telling the user to first Like the facebook page to see the coupon code
- Then if he likes it, he is taken to another page or image where the coupon code is shown to him

How can I achieve this

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check the signedRequest provided by Facebook when a user visit your page to see if a user has liked the page. Then depending on the signedRequest, you can redirect the user to different pages.

There are two ways to do it:

1. In the frontend, use JavaScript to parse the signedRequest
2. In the backend, use something like the PHP SDK
   (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) to check the
   signedRequest

You can refer to another post here for details: [Facebook how to check if user has liked page and show content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246449/facebook-how-to-check-if-user-has-liked-page-and-show-content)

Answer (score 0):

Before working on a solution for your problem, you have a legal issue here. You **cannot** use the act of Liking your page as an entry to your promotion!

> iii.    You must not condition registration or entry upon the user
>   taking any action using any Facebook features or functionality other
>   than liking a Page, checking in to a Place, or connecting to your app.
>   For example, you must not condition registration or entry upon the
>   user liking a Wall post, or commenting or uploading a photo on a Wall.
>   iv.    You must not use Facebook features or functionality as a
>   promotion’s registration or entry mechanism. For example, the act of
>   liking a Page or checking in to a Place cannot automatically register
>   or enter a promotion participant.

[Reference](https://www.facebook.com/page_guidelines.php).

Now how to achieve this is up to you and the technology your are using. ([Here's an example](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page/5331541#5331541) of doing this in PHP)