# Check if a user Is fan of a Facebook page

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, sdk

After logged in I am trying to return if the user is either not a fan of a Facebook page, but the result is always "undefined". But if I replace "return" to "alert" works perfectly.

```
function pageFan()
{
    FB.api({ method: 'pages.isFan', page_id: '175625039138809' }, function(response) {
        showAlert(response);
    });
}

function showAlert(response)
{
    if (response == true) {  
        return 'like the Application.';
    } else {
        return "doesn't like the Application.";
    }
}

var like = pageFan();
document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = like; //return undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has already [been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246449/facebook-how-to-check-if-user-has-liked-page-and-show-content).

Relevant Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session) {

          var user_id = response.session.uid;
          var page_id = "40796308305"; //coca cola
          var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
          var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);

          the_query.wait(function(rows) {

              if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                  $("#container_like").show();

                  //here you could also do some ajax and get the content for a "liker" instead of simply showing a hidden div in the page.

              } else {
                  $("#container_notlike").show();
                  //and here you could get the content for a non liker in ajax...
              }
          });


      } else {
        // user is not logged in
      }
    });
```

Comment: response.session is outdated, instead the correct way is: response.authResponse

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `return` in `showAlert` is not returning "into" the `pageFan` function. The `showAlert` function is passed as a callback, meaning it will be called later, outside of `pageFan`'s execution. I think you need to read [more about callback functions and asynchronous programming](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/).

```
function showAlert(response)
{
    if (response == true) {  
        document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = 'like the Application.';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = "doesn't like the Application.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand, but what is the solution?

Comment: The solution is to modify the `debug` element within `showAlert`. Edited answer