# Facebook like check code

Tags: javascript, facebook, callback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook how to check if user has liked page and show content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246449/facebook-how-to-check-if-user-has-liked-page-and-show-content)

I've code:

```
FB.api({ method: 'pages.isFan', page_id: 'XXX',}, function(resp) {
    if (resp == true) {
      alert('user_id likes the Application.');
    } else if(resp.error_code) {
      alert(resp.error_msg);
    } else {
      alert("user_id doesn't like the Application.");
    }
});
```

I want to check  current visitors which they already logged in facebook whether like specifed fanpage (page_id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not trivial to implement.

Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6314568/477176

Comment: In the future, please use moderator flags to alert us to duplicate questions. Thanks!