# how to hide content until user likes your page without fbml?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api)

how can i show or display information only if the user is fan or likes my page without using fbml. I have some old code there.

Something like:

```
<fb:visible-to-connection>
    Show content to the user
    <fb:else>
        <div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">
               Like the page inorder to view the content.
        </div>
    </fb:else>
</fb:visible-to-connection>
```

But fbml has been deprecated, I need to this by javascript without using server related code, like php or aspx.

Thanks for any help.

And forgive my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a handler function to the facebook like buttons click event that enables displaying of the data.

But without actually checking with the facebook servers you cannot be sure and therefore a user can always fake it by just calling the javascript function displaying the information, for which you don't check if the user behaves.

Comment: Thanks.
But how do I keep on showing the information when they reenter the page. I need to check if they like. Not the like action.

Comment: then ask the facebook server or save the fact that the user clicked it in YOUR database via an ajax called spawned upon click on the like button.

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed explanation of how to accomplish this using only Javascript at [Facebook how to check if user has liked page and show content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246449/facebook-how-to-check-if-user-has-liked-page-and-show-content)