# Client side Facebook "like gate" without https

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to set up a "like gate" where a user has to like a page before seeing certain content on a website (not on Facebook itself). I've found some great resources on SO an elsewhere on how to do it, but I'm running into an issue with `http` vs. `https`. My site is not loaded over https, but the Facebook login popup is. The error:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://yoursite.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com". The frame being accessed set "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame requesting access did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.`

I'm currently using the code here: https://github.com/vavrecan/facebook-fangate, but have also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246449/facebook-how-to-check-if-user-has-liked-page-and-show-content) useful.

How can I show a user content only if they've liked a specific Facebook page, without using https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like-gating is discouraged via Platform Policies, and Like-gates via SignedRequests will stop working on November 6th 2014. Have a look at my answer at

[How to check if people liked my Facebook FanPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417638/how-to-check-if-people-liked-my-facebook-fanpage/25420196#25420196)

The error itself is about CORS and not HTTP vs. HTTPS imho.