# How to check if people liked my Facebook FanPage

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

There are many questions and answers about this. But nowadays Facebook changes their Privacy. Any Application that request for user_likes permission must be review by Facebook before using. I've tried many times to explain to Facebook review team about my app, but they did not accept, because my application (a web game using HTML5 and JavaScript) require people like my fan page before play.

So my question is: Is there any to bypass Facebook privacy?
I have a Like Box on the same page as the game screen (where i need to check Like), so any solution (like: analyze DOM elements, capture screen can pass through image recognition) will fine.

Answer (score 1):

There's no (compliant) way to bypass the security. If you'd find a way and FB finds out, it will surely remove your app.

Like-Gating is no longer desired by FB on its platform, there are several articles in their docs about that:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_1_90_day_deprecations
- https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/08/07/Graph-API-v2.1/
- https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse

> You must not incentivize people to use social plugins or to like a Page. **This includes offering rewards, or gating apps or app content based on whether or not a person has liked a Page.** It remains acceptable to incentivize people to login to your app, checkin at a place or enter a promotion on your app's Page. To ensure quality connections and help businesses reach the people who matter to them, we want people to like Pages because they want to connect and hear from the business, not because of artificial incentives. We believe this update will benefit people and advertisers alike.

Comment: I carefully read Facebook privacy policy. Just hope someone find out a graceful way :). Thank you all anyway

Comment: There's none, sorry. It's no longer desired by FB.

Answer (score -1):

Facebook recently enacted a policy disallowing developers to make users like a page before getting certain content.
Read this: http://gizmodo.com/facebook-has-banned-likes-for-content-1618101824

TLDR: Facebook does not allow app developers to incentivize locking up content for likes, so you can't hold access to your app hostage by forcing users to like your page. If you are developing an app currently this applies to you. Old apps will have to comply by Nov 5, 2014.