# Javascript Error Null is not an Object

Tags: javascript, html

Im getting a error in the Web Inspector as shown below:

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'myButton.onclick = function() {
var userName = myTextfield.value;
greetUser(userName);

return false;

}')
```

Here is my Code (HTML):

```
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<p id="myParagraph">This is an example website</p>

<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="myTextfield" placeholder="Type your name" />
  <input type="submit" id="myButton" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Here is the JS:

```
var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
var myTextfield = document.getElementById("myTextfield");

function greetUser(userName) {
var greeting = "Hello " + userName + "!";
document.getElementsByTagName ("h2")[0].innerHTML = greeting;
}

myButton.onclick = function() {
var userName = myTextfield.value;
greetUser(userName);

return false;

}
```

Any Idea why I am getting the error?

Comment: This isn't your problem, but I'd recommend using a `submit` event handler on the form rather than a `click` event handler on the button. Then it will work if someone presses enter, too.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Put the code so it executes after the elements are defined, either with a *DOM ready* callback or place the source under the elements in the HTML.

`document.getElementById()` returns `null` if the element couldn't be found. Property assignment can only occur on objects. `null` is not an object (contrary to what `typeof` says).

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for the quick reply I moved the source. Being new to Javascript could you explain what a DOM ready callback is? But thanks for your answer it helped :)

Comment: @MarkH I could, but [here is a better explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978740/javascript-how-to-detect-if-document-has-loaded-ie-7-firefox-3).

Comment: I'm having this error -  I am unclear on this answer. What does Alex mean by 'place the source under the elements in the HTML" ?

Comment: When I asked my question about understanding what Alex meant by 'place the source under the elements in the HTML", I had not processed Fiddle's response below. Now I get it.

Answer (score 7):

Any JS code which executes and deals with DOM elements should execute after the DOM elements have been created. JS code is interpreted from top to down as layed out in the HTML.
So, if there is a  tag before the DOM elements, the JS code within script tag will execute as the browser parses the HTML page.

So, in your case, you can put your DOM interacting code inside a function so that only function is defined but not executed.

Then you can add an event listener for document load to execute the function.

That will give you something like:

```
<script>
  function init() {
    var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
    var myTextfield = document.getElementById("myTextfield");
    myButton.onclick = function() {
      var userName = myTextfield.value;
      greetUser(userName);
    }
  }

  function greetUser(userName) {
    var greeting = "Hello " + userName + "!";
    document.getElementsByTagName ("h2")[0].innerHTML = greeting;
  }

  document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
      init();
    }
  });

</script>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<p id="myParagraph">This is an example website</p>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="myTextfield" placeholder="Type your name" />
  <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Fiddle at - http://jsfiddle.net/poonia/qQMEg/4/

Answer (score 2):

Try loading your javascript after.

Try this:

```
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<p id="myParagraph">This is an example website</p>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="myTextfield" placeholder="Type your name" />
  <input type="submit" id="myButton" value="Go" />
</form>

<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the error because the elements are undefined ,so you need to add `window.onload` event which this event will defined your elements when the window is loaded.

```
window.addEventListener('load',Loaded,false);


    function Loaded(){
    var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
    var myTextfield = document.getElementById("myTextfield");

    function greetUser(userName) {
    var greeting = "Hello " + userName + "!";
    document.getElementsByTagName ("h2")[0].innerHTML = greeting;
    }

    myButton.onclick = function() {
    var userName = myTextfield.value;
    greetUser(userName);

    return false;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with alex about making sure the DOM is loaded. I also think that the submit button will trigger a refresh.

This is what I would do

```
<html>
<head>
<title>webpage</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myButton;
var myTextfield;

function setup() {
  myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
  myTextfield = document.getElementById("myTextfield");
  myButton.onclick = function() {
    var userName = myTextfield.value;
    greetUser(userName);
    return false;
  }
}

function greetUser(userName) {
  var greeting = "Hello " + userName + "!";
  document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].innerHTML = greeting;
}

</script>
<body onload="setup()">
  <h2>Hello World!</h2>
  <p id="myParagraph">This is an example website</p>

  <form>
    <input type="text" id="myTextfield" placeholder="Type your name" />
    <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Go" />
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

have fun!