# Remove error when evaluating value Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, error-handling

Before you look past this question, I know exactly what is causing this error and why. I've got an object and I'm effectively testing to see if it's empty by checking it's length; when the array is empty, it causes roughly 30 errors per `$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter')` call.

Is there a way to stop these errors from being thrown constantly/is there a better way to test if an array is filled with something?

JS:

```
$scope.checkLeague = function () {
        if ($scope.favs.length > 0){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
```

Error:

```
null is not an object (evaluating '$scope.favs.length')
```

**Edit:** Having looked further into the problem, `$scope.favs` is initialised as `null` to try and combat this error, but is being set as an empty array later in the code, as this is a REST response. The problem still lies in successfully catching an array that will always be instantiated but maybe empty. Logging the array to the console will always produce `[]`.

Comment: Maybe check for null...

Comment: Already tried that, it always evaluates as true

Comment: Do you Check $scope as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check $scope.favs value before:

```
$scope.checkLeague = function () {
        if ($scope.favs && $scope.favs.length > 0){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
```

Comment: Issue is `$scope.favs` is created at runtime so it's technically always present, filled or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$scope.checkLeague = function () {
    if ($scope.favs.hasOwnProperty("length") && $scope.favs.length > 0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A length property with "0" or `null` value doesn't necessarily mean that the object is empty. Check this up

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
a.key1 = "test";
a.length; // <- 4
Object.keys(a); // <- ["0", "1", "2", "3", "key1"]
a.length = null;
a; // <- [];
Object.keys(a); // <- ["key1"]
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a); // <- ["length", "key1"]
```

you might need to check the `Object.keys().length`

Comment: Unfortunately, all I'm getting is `Error: null is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys($scope.favs)')`

Comment: Obviously there is no such a `favs` thing. You might consider having a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207922/javascript-error-null-is-not-an-object