# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '*')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

For the below code:

```
var item = cartModel.getlist()[index];
if((item.isDepo()) {
    // Some code
} else if(!permission.hasPermissionToVoidSKU()) {
    // Some code
} else if(item.sku.indexOf(mposConstants.RESTOCK_FEE_SKU) > -1){
                // Some code 
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'item.sku.indexOf')

If item object is null, the error is something different (see below). **In what scenario will this error be thrown?**

*Update:*

If `item.sku` is null, the error is:

> [FATAL] [] [-] ["TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null

If `item` is null, the error is:

> [FATAL] [] [-] ["TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDepo' of null

Comment: `item` or `item.sku` is null, check them in console

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: @freginold I want know in what scenario this error will be thrown

Comment: you lost the reference then (it was deleted?); the referring function was called before the element was parsed into the DOM

Comment: What errors do you get if `item` or `item.sku` are `undefined` instead of `null`?

Comment: did you double check the value of `mposConstants.RESTOCK_FEE_SKU`?

Answer (score 12):

The reason for the different error messages is quite simply that they are produced by different browsers. The error is the same (`sku` on the object `item` is `null`).

Given the following code

```html
<script>
  var item = {sku: null};
  item.sku.indexOf("");
</script>
```

here is some error messages for different browsers:

- Firefox: `TypeError: item.sku is null`
- Firefox Developer Edition: `TypeError: item.sku is null, can't access property "indexOf" of it`
- Opera: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null
  at example.html:3`
- Safari: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'item.sku.indexOf')`

To get the error message you have gotten, `item` must be defined as an object, and `sku` must be set to `null`. If `sku` were `undefined`, you would have gotten an error message like this (Safari): `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.sku.indexOf')`. If `item` was `null`, you would have gotten something like this: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'item.sku')`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14207932/5463636) and others, it sounds like you're getting that error because a function is called before the DOM element it references or acts upon has been loaded.

In the snippet of code you provided, I don't see a direct reference to any DOM elements, but I would suggest calling your script after your HTML has finished rendering (i.e. by putting any `<script>` tags at the end of your HTML, or by using a `$(document).ready()` call if you use jQuery).