# Connecting dApps in embedded browser with custom made wallet in react native

Tags: react-native, web3js, wallet-connect

What are the APIs that's available to do this, I've only found Wallet Connect that can do this, are there any other that I've missed ?

I've try integrating with Wallet Connect V1 sdk, but encounter a problem

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNRandomBytes.seed')

is there any workaround on this ? did I missing something ?

the error triggers right after I imported Wallet Connect V1 sdk

the code :

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import WalletConnect from "@walletconnect/client";

export default function Login({ navigation }) {
return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center", marginTop: 10 }}>{secret?.address}</Text>
            <View style={{ padding: 10, flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
                <TextInput style={{ padding: 10, borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 10, flex: 2, margin: 5 }} placeholder='WC Connection...' onChangeText={(e) => setWc(e)} />
                <View style={{ margin: 5, flex: 1 }}>
                    <Button title='Connect'/>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
                <Button title='Generate Wallet' />
            </View>
            <WebView
                source={{ uri: 'https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap' }}
                style={styles.container}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    },
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Error Null is not an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207922/javascript-error-null-is-not-an-object)

Comment: No, I think it's a problem with the sdk it self.. cause like I said, it's only happened when I imported the sdk package to my project.. Still finding solutions though,  open for any other SDKs options