# .checked is not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript

I have piece of Javascript code.

```
function checkProductId(value){
        checkboxid = value;
        // First create an event
        var click_ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
        // initialize the event
        click_ev.initEvent("click", true, true);

        if(document.getElementById(value).checked){
            // trigger the evevnt
            document.getElementById("addproduct").dispatchEvent(click_ev);
        } else {
            document.getElementById("removeproductdata").dispatchEvent(click_ev);
        }
    }
```

When I am load my page in safari browser its give me error:

```
'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(value).checked')
```

And `document.getElementById(value).checked` its not working.

Comment: yes.. In all browser its work fine, but not working in safari browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try

```
document.getElementById(value).getAttribute('checked)
```

Maybe there is something wrong with your HTML?

Does

```
document.getElementById(value)
```

it return something more then null value?

Comment: no its not getting more then null value

Comment: so you have no dom elem with the given id.
Please print this 'value' or alert it
window.alert(value)
to check if this is what you expected OK?

Comment: yes i have alert value and i got which i want

Comment: so the element wasn't loaded properly. Do you wrap you js in the document.ready() function?
Read about it please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978740/javascript-how-to-detect-if-document-has-loaded-ie-7-firefox-3

Comment: now its working fine... when page is load at that time value pass null.

Comment: because dom object hasn't been loaded yet. This what I think at least. I hope this short discussion helped you a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `document.getElementById(value)` is returning null. Make sure that the `value` you are passing corresponds to the id of an element on the page.

If this isn't helpful, please add the html and the code that calls the function to your question.

Comment: i am passing value as an id of element, and its not a passing null.

Comment: @PrashantParekh You are passing a string, fir example "foo", and you need a corresponding `<input type="checkbox" id="foo" />`. You don't have one, so `document.getElementById("foo")` is returning null.