# JS Drag and drop with DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, drag-and-drop

With [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/#disqus_thread) tutorial i made simple drag and drop web app. But I cant do it with DOM. Here is my code [jsfinddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7c3v0s1s/2/) . It is not working on jsfiddle but if u download it it will. The script should be placed behind the divs. When you uncoment `<div class="column" draggable="true"><span>A</span></div>` it will work (not in jsfiddle). So how can i made it with DOM ?

Comment: are you sure you know what a DOM is?

Comment: i want to make HTML doc dynamically ... so i want to create it with DOM. Why are you asking ?? is something wrong with that init() function ?

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem

Comment: i want to apply those drag events on DOM created objects...

Comment: I think they are using DOM as a synonym for vanilla javascript.

Comment: This is dom http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_methods.asp

Comment: I think the confusion is stemming from, any manipulation made to the page is made through the DOM.  So saying you want to do it with DOM is not very clear.  Saying you want to do it dynamically or something of that nature would be more descriptive of what your after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off the assumption you meant doing the draggable with dynamically created elements, I've updated your jsfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/7c3v0s1s/6/  I wrapped the code in a namespace while doing the changes.

HTML

```
<div class="containter">
    <div id="columns"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var localNameSpace = {
    dragSrcEl: null
    , bindDraggables: function() {
        var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .column');

        [].forEach.call(cols, function(col) {
            col.addEventListener('dragstart', localNameSpace.handleDragStart, false);
            col.addEventListener('dragenter', localNameSpace.handleDragEnter, false);
            col.addEventListener('dragover', localNameSpace.handleDragOver, false);
            col.addEventListener('dragleave', localNameSpace.handleDragLeave, false);
            col.addEventListener('drop', localNameSpace.handleDrop, false);
            col.addEventListener('dragend', localNameSpace.handleDragEnd, false);
        });
    }
    , createDraggables: function() {
        var colDiv = document.getElementById('columns');
        var divC = document.createElement('div');
        var spanC = document.createElement('span');

        divC.className = 'column';
        divC.draggable = 'true';
        spanC.innerHTML = 'A';

        divC.appendChild(spanC);
        colDiv.appendChild(divC);
    }
    , handleDrop: function(e) {
        if(e.stopPropagation){
            e.stopPropagation();
        }

        if(dragSrcEl != this){
            localNameSpace.dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
        }
        return false;
    }
    , handleDragEnd: function(e) {
        var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .column');
        this.style.opacity = 1;

        [].forEach.call(cols, function(col){
            col.classList.remove('over');
        }); 
    }       
    , handleDragEnter: function(e) {
        this.classList.add('over');
    }
    , handleDragLeave: function(e) {
        this.classList.remove('over');
    }
    , handleDragOver: function(e) {
        if(e.preventDefault){
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
        return false;
    }
    , handleDragStart: function(e) {
        this.style.opacity = 0.4;
        localNameSpace.dragSrcEl = this;
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
    }
    , init: function() {
        var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if (document.readyState === "complete") {
                clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);
                localNameSpace.createDraggables();
                localNameSpace.bindDraggables();
            }
        }, 10);
    }
};

localNameSpace.init();
```

Comment: Reference to the checking ready state code block: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978740/javascript-how-to-detect-if-document-has-loaded-ie-7-firefox-3

Comment: i added for loop to create more elemenst http://jsfiddle.net/7c3v0s1s/7/ but is says Uncaught ReferenceError: dragSrcEl is not defined

Comment: dragSrcEl, in the manner in which I used it above, belongs to localNameSpace.  so to use it you would need to fully qualify it: localNameSpace.dragSrcEl