# open window and run function on that window

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'd like to open a new window, this window has a list of objects, and these objects should be filtered based on a selection from the previous window. I figured I can filter the list through a function, but how do I run said function?

This is what I am able to do:

```
var popup = window.open('pageURL');
    $(popup.document).ready(function() {
        // this is where function should be
        popup.alert('HelloWorld');
    });
```

But how do I change the alert to a function?

If I have a function **on my other app** , `function test() { alert('HelloWorld'};`
How do I run this function from my first app?

Swapping `popup.alert('HelloWorld');` with `popup.test();` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need the reference to the window opened to call functions in the new window, like:

```
var oNewWindow = window.open("new.window.url", "mywindow");
oNewWindow.onload = function(){oNewWindow.window.newWindowFunction();};
```

Comment: i have that `popup.test()` where `popup` is the reference and `test()` is the function, does not work, error: `object doesn't support property or method`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution

```
var popup = window.open('http://s234-0057/actiontracker/SiteAssets/Avvik/html/app.aspx');

var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (popup.document.readyState === "complete") {
        clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);
        popup.test();
    }
}, 50);
```

Where I check if the popup window is ready, and when it is, cancel check and run function. Solution is from [top answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978740/javascript-how-to-detect-if-document-has-loaded-ie-7-firefox-3), by @this.lau_

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
function myFunction(){
    alert('HelloWorld');
}

var popup = window.open('pageURL');
$(popup.document).ready(function() {
    popup.eval(myFunction + "");
    popup.myFunction();
});
```

`myFunction` in file that contains this code will run in page with `pageURL` address.