# Delete localstorage after url have finished loading view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I pass url parameters stored in a localstorage to get details of a particular item. i want to delete localstorage variable after view is loaded, but what i'm experincing is, the localstorage variables get deleted before the view is loaded preventing the data to load correctly

```
$scope.pushpayment_id = localStorage.getItem("pushpayment_id")
$scope.pushshop_id = localStorage.getItem("pushshop_id")
$scope.pushmessage = localStorage.getItem("push_message")

var startapp=function() {
  if($scope.pushmessage== "payment"){
    $location.path('/tab/new_payment_push/'+ $scope.pushpayment_id + '/' + $scope.pushshop_id);
  }
}
localStorage.removeItem("pushpayment_id")
localStorage.removeItem("pushshop_id")
localStorage.removeItem("push_message")
```

Answer (score 1):

An Angular solution can be this:

When the locations change successfully you can make your operations, also can control from what path are you comming and where are you going.

**EDIT** place this on your `.run()`, tell me if you need more information about it.

```
 $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(ev, newUrl, oldUrl, newState, oldState){
       if(newUrl === '/myLocation/To/Delete'){
           localStorage.clear();
       }       
  });
```

See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#$locationChangeSuccess) more information about the events of `$location`

Comment: i'm new to angularjs, can you put it in my script?

Comment: can you tell me where are you evaluating the location??, if you place this every where should work, just control what location you can this works

Answer (score 0):

You could clear localStorage when the window is done loading with jQuery like this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    localStorage.clear();
});
```

If you want to use pure javascript to detect if the page is done loading, you could try this option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7088499/5709703

Answer (score 0):

you could use the load event callback to remove your localStorage.
in javascript, use

```
$(window).load(function() {
    //What you need to do.
})
```

Make sure you have Jquery installed for before trying, or else you will get and error.
You can learn more on the window object in Javascript on [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp)
Hopes it helps !

- Nic