# Why InternetExplorer 11 doesn't fire events in inactive tab?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a problem with IE11: I open new window in js and bind to it an event in old window. But it isn't work when old window is inactive. When I fast switch tabs -it work and also it work when I use window.blur to remove focus from new tab.

There is my code:

```
var win = window.open(url);
//win.blur(); trash solution
this.bindLoadEvent(win, function() {
     element.invoke();
});

bindLoadEvent: function (win, handler) {
     if (win.addEventListener) {
            win.addEventListener('load', handler, true);
     } else {
            win.attachEvent('onload', handler);
     }
}
```

It's seems like IE doesn't fire events in inactive tabs.

P.S. Also I tested it in Firefox and Chrome - it's work great.

Comment: I found this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537636(v=vs.85).aspx but I still can 't fire event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load event may occur before you attach handler.

Try to check whether window already loaded before you attach event handler:

```
bindLoadEvent = function (win, handler) {
    if (win.document.readyState === "complete") {
      setTimeout(handler, 0);
    } else if (win.addEventListener) {
      win.addEventListener('load', handler, true);
    } else {
      win.attachEvent('onload', handler);
    }
  };
```

For more information check [How to detect if document has loaded (IE 7/Firefox 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978740/javascript-how-to-detect-if-document-has-loaded-ie-7-firefox-3) and [Detecting the onload event of a window opened with window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030859/detecting-the-onload-event-of-a-window-opened-with-window-open) questions.