# Javascript output as value of hidden input

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

How can I set the ouput of this javascript function as the value for a hidden input on a html form?

```
document.write(states[i][1]);
```

works fine but I cannot get it to fill in the value with the code as shown below.

```
    if (to == 'abbr'){
        input = input.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return 
        txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
        for(i = 0; i < states.length; i++){
            if(states[i][0] == input){
            document.getElementById("sid").value = (states[i][1]);
                 }
             }    
         } 
     }       

</script>
<form action="we2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="sid" name="s1"/>
<input type="submit" value="Verify">
</form>
```

What is wrong with this code / what is the right way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a easier solution by just turning the entire function into a variable then the variable into the DOM:

```
var response = abbrState('<?php echo $_GET['state']; ?>', 'abbr');

document.getElementById("sid").value = response;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="HiddenInput" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById("HiddenInput").value = someFunction();
```

Comment: I see that you are trying to assign values to input field using a loop. Have to really added so many input field's in your HTML before calling this function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The script is just state abbreviation conversion array from github so all the inputs above the form are only part of the function.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me except this part (states[i][1]). You are asking to set output of a funtion to the input field but states seems to be a var. Please rectify.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if `states[i][0] == input` evaluates to `true`?

Comment: Yes, the function works fine with document.write so the if function is true.

Comment: can you log this value ? ```states[i][1]```

Comment: Like console.log or give an example?

Comment: inside ```if(states[i][0] == input)``` statement insert ```console.log(states[i][1]) ``` do you get any value?

Comment: Yes that returns a value. Like I said this is just a conversion array so input Oregon, console log shows OR for that.

Comment: Same with document.write. 'OR' shows on screen, but nothing is shown for document.getElementById

Comment: as @ShivamRajput mentioned your javascript code can evaluate before the html elements are loaded.Wrap your code in this statement https://stackoverflow.com/a/7088499/6947248

Answer (score 0):

Write JavaScript code after html code end in your page or at the end of page.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

HTML:

```
<div style="display:none" id="example"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function addTextNode(text) {
  var newtext = document.createTextNode(text),
      element = document.getElementById('example');

  element.appendChild(newtext);
}

function yourFunctionDataHere(){
    return 'test1234';
}


addTextNode(yourFunctionDataHere());
```

Just make sure, that the return type of your function is of type string. If you want to see the output simply remove the `style="display:none"` from the div in the above example.

Try it online on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2as75v93/).